# How do I wrtite the current IP of tun0 into a txt file with a shell script?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sh, putty, ifconfig

```
#!/bin/sh
/sbin/ifconfig tun0 | grep 'inet addr:' | cut -d: -f2 | awk '{print $1}' > ./tun0_ip.txt
```

This works very good when I put it into the command line.
However it does not work with a sh script.

What am I doing wrong?
Why do some commands not work with a sh script?

```
~$ bash -x ./reset.sh
+ echo /sbin/ifconfig tun0
+ grep 'inet addr:'
+ cut -d: -f2
+ awk '{print $1}'
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange that you are testing with bash, while giving `#!/bin/sh` as shebang line.

However this is probably not the reason this does not work. Definitely, whether you run some commands from the command line or from a script with the exact same environment, they should not give you a different result.

Maybe the user that calls the script has a different locale, so the output of ifconfig is no more 'inet addr' but something else? Or some environment variable that changes the form of ifconfigs output is not exported?

You can find out only, by going step by step. Looking at the script it should be some problem with ifconfig not giving you, what you expect. So simply take a look at the output of that from the script, unchanged.

Comment: I run all the commands via ssh (Putty). Could that be a problem?

Comment: Just show us what you do exactly. 
And give the output of ifconfig, you get from the script.

Comment: : error fetching interface information: Device not found

Comment: Ah, so now let's see what interfaces you have by calling ifconfig without parameters.

Comment: : not found: reset.sh: ifconfig //it works when I write the command manually via ssh

Comment: You have to call something like 'ssh host "/some/path/reset.sh"